# How to convert json/js models to gltf models in three.js

Tags: three.js

i used to convert my obj&mtl models to .js models using three.jsV84 convertor tools.And my original obj&mtl models backups are lost.I need to convert those .js models to gltf models,since i have updated my three version to V100 in my project.I used [blackthread.io/gltf-converter/](https://blackthread.io/gltf-converter/) and it seems it doesnot support multimaterial so my textures in .js models are lost.Is there a solution?txs.

I've tried using threeV84 editor to convert my .js models to obj.But the mtl textures are lost.

Comment: you can try to convert it to fbx/obj and then to gltf using blender 2.8

Comment: @Tomasz Zieliński I've tried converting them to obj,but the textures are lost.These .js format models is generated by .obj&.mtl files.So it may not work if the converting result does not contain a mtl file at all.And i could't find any solution converting .js model to fbx format.